# Software Update problem libplacebo18 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, package-management, updates

This has been since the last update message I can't install any other programs because of this error, please help.

> If you are using third party repositories then disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
>   Now run the following command in a terminal: apt-get install -f
>   Transaction failed: The package system is broken
>    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>
> mpv: Depends: libplacebo18 (>= 1.18.0) but it is not installed
>        Depends: libxrandr2 (>= 2:1.2.99.3) but 2:1.5.1-1 is installed

That's the message that appears after I run the installer. Than I tried to run

```
sudo apt update
```

And many other commands in order to update the package but it seems to not working every time.

> sudo apt --fix-broken install
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   Correcting dependencies... Done
>   The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
>     libdav1d2 libplacebo7
>   Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
>   The following additional packages will be installed:
>     libplacebo18
>   The following NEW packages will be installed
>     libplacebo18
>   0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 29 not to upgrade.
>   1 not fully installed or removed.
>   Need to get 0 B/129 kB of archives.
>   After this operation, 360 kB of additional disk space will be used.
>   Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
>   (Reading database ... 249564 files and directories currently installed.)
>   Preparing to unpack .../libplacebo18_1.18.0-1~bionic1_amd64.deb ...
>   Unpacking libplacebo18:amd64 (1.18.0-1~bionic1) ...
>   dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libplacebo18_1.18.0-1~bionic1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
>    trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libplacebo.so.18', which is also in package libplacebo7:amd64 1.8.0-1~bionic
>   dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>    /var/cache/apt/archives/libplacebo18_1.18.0-1~bionic1_amd64.deb
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

That's something that could help I have no idea what's happening.

Comment: The problem is: "Unpacking libplacebo18:amd64 (1.18.0-1~bionic1) ... dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libplacebo18_1.18.0-1~bionic1_amd64.deb (--unpack): trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libplacebo.so.18', which is also in package libplacebo7:amd64 1.8.0-1~bionic " You cannot have BOTH packages installed at the same time - they are *incompatible*. Pick one, uninstall the other.

Comment: Which one should I uninstall?

Comment: You should uninstall whatever non-Ubuntu software broke your updates. That should be your priority. Adding *more* non-Ubuntu software usually just makes things worse. Whatever you are trying to install that requires libplacebo, find a way that doesn't break your system. FYI: libplacebo7 is in the Ubuntu repositories starting with 19.04, so a newer release of Ubuntu might have more of what you need.

Comment: Okay, I tried to install it and then purge it i didn't work. I followed through this https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa and still couldn't help. Every time I pasted a command it showed me this error message You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 mpv : Depends: libplacebo18 (>= 1.18.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I fixed it by force overwriting the package

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libplacebo18_1.18.0-1~bionic1_amd64.deb
```

And then I used this command to fix any broken packages.

```
sudo apt -f install
```